# Extract list data from CSV file

Tags: python

I have csv file with below sample content, i need to store just the list part into csv format.

file.csv:

```
Row 1: [123, abc, aa-dd daw, 122, 2011-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, None, GA GH, 1.9912109375]
Row 2: [234, bcd, bc-dd acs, 332, 2012-11-11 00:00:00, None, addad, None, GB GG, 1.22]
Row 3: [345, cda, cd-dd adc, 12312, 2013-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, dsa, GV GA, 1.925262]
```

Code:

```
import re

file=open('file.csv')
file_contents=file.read()
regx = re.compile(r'\[(.*)\]')
column_fetch=regx.findall(file_contents)
print column_fetch
```

Expected Output (file.csv):

```
123, abc, aa-dd daw, 122, 2011-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, None, GA GH, 1.9912109375
234, bcd, bc-dd acs, 332, 2012-11-11 00:00:00, None, addad, None, GB GG, 1.22
345, cda, cd-dd adc, 12312, 2013-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, dsa, GV GA, 1.925262
```

Actual Output:

```
[123, abc, aa-dd daw, 122, 2011-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, None, GA GH, 1.9912109375 234, bcd, bc-dd acs, 332, 2012-11-11 00:00:00, None, addad, None, GB GG, 1.22 345, cda, cd-dd adc, 12312, 2013-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, dsa, GV GA, 1.925262]
```

Comment: Not sure I am following. Your example of file.csv does not show content in CSV format.

Comment: The mix between "from csv" and "into csv" doesn't make things clearer either. Also, please take some time to do some research on that topic, you are (probably) trying to solve a solved problem. Just use the right tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

with open("data.csv", 'r')as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        row = ' '.join(row)
        print(row[7:].strip("[]"))
```

OUTPUT:

[image: out]

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, you get line as lists, then you can do whatever you want:

```
import re

file=open('test-001.csv')
file_contents=file.readlines()
regx = re.compile(r'\[(.*)\]')
for line in file_contents:
  line_fetch=regx.findall(line)
  print (line_fetch)
  # print (line_fetch.__class__)  # uncomment to see
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is caused by your regular expression `r'\[(.*)\]'` because `*` is greedy search, so it is looking for longest possible match, so you get one starting at first `[` and ending at last `]`, to avoid such situation use `*?` meaning non-greedy search, for example:

```
data = '''Row 1: [123, abc, aa-dd daw, 122, 2011-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, None, GA GH, 1.9912109375]
Row 2: [234, bcd, bc-dd acs, 332, 2012-11-11 00:00:00, None, addad, None, GB GG, 1.22]
Row 3: [345, cda, cd-dd adc, 12312, 2013-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, dsa, GV GA, 1.925262]'''
rows = [i[1] for i in re.findall(r'(\[)(.*?)(\])',data)]
print(rows)
```

output:

```
['123, abc, aa-dd daw, 122, 2011-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, None, GA GH, 1.9912109375', '234, bcd, bc-dd acs, 332, 2012-11-11 00:00:00, None, addad, None, GB GG, 1.22', '345, cda, cd-dd adc, 12312, 2013-11-11 00:00:00, None, None, dsa, GV GA, 1.925262']
```

For example clarity I omitted read from and write to file parts, assigning string to `data` directly. Note that I used grouping of regular expression creating three groups:

for `[`

for actual data

for `]`

and then extracted middle one.

Answer (score 0):

As someone familiar with Pandas I'd do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('file.csv')
pd.to_csv('file_out.csv')
```

But I'm not sure that is exactly what you want. At least when you have the csv as a pd.DataFrame you have quite some options.

Comment: This does not work since there is normal text as well in file. Error is `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data.`